# SQLITE Query results into a temp table

Tags: sqlite, common-table-expression, create-table

I haven't used `SQLite` before and can't figure out the syntax, I have this working in `SQL Server` if it helps.

I need to put the results into a temp table so I can reuse them.

//SQL Server

```
WITH FT_CTE AS
(
SELECT pID, cID FROM brFTNode_Children 
WHERE pID = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT e.pID, e.cID FROM brFTNode_Children e
    INNER JOIN FT_CTE ftCTE on (ftCTE.cID = e.pID)
)
SELECT * INTO #ParentChild FROM FT_CTE;
```

//SQLite try

```
WITH FT_CTE AS
(
SELECT pID, cID FROM brFTNode_Children 
WHERE pID = 1
UNION ALL
    SELECT e.pID, e.cID FROM brFTNode_Children e
    INNER JOIN FT_CTE ftCTE on (ftCTE.cID = e.pID)
)
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ParentChild as SELECT * FROM FT_CTE;
```

I get `Error near "CREATE": syntax error`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [CREATE TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) does not allow CTEs, but the SELECT does:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ParentChild AS
WITH FT_CTE AS (
    SELECT pID, cID FROM brFTNode_Children 
    WHERE pID = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.pID, e.cID FROM brFTNode_Children e
    INNER JOIN FT_CTE ftCTE ON (ftCTE.cID = e.pID)
)
SELECT * FROM FT_CTE;
```